# CSS - image overflow tricks

Tags: html, css

I'm stucking with some design techniques where I want to make image item box like this

[image]

Where the actual image can be upto maximum height of **300px** and width of **225px**. The width and height of the item box including the image and the text is **190px x 190px** I'm using this image http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7122/7424355198_72620895bd_m.jpg

I tried using `overflow: hidden` for the image item to hide it's height below to show the image text. But I'm getting only like this http://jsfiddle.net/Dkh4q/

Could anyone tell the mistake I've done?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

For more information about the expected result, if you can login to zerply, then please check this http://zerply.com/christievdc/portfolio for example.

**SUMMARY**

Finally it's a silly mistake I've done that I put extra **}** thing in **addmenu-item**. Thanks answerers!

Comment: Have you considered using `background-image`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, for variable width and height you will need to use some javascript.

```
.addmenu-item {
margin-top:25px;
float:left;
overflow:auto;
background: #F4F4F4;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-transition: color 50ms cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715);
-moz-transition: color 50ms cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715);
-o-transition: color 50ms cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715);
transition: color 50ms cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715);
}
```

Comment: Please check this now! http://jsfiddle.net/Dkh4q/23/ How can I make that item inside the master `<div class="set addbox">` and Why do I need to use javascript here?

Comment: add overflow:auto; to the .addbox class and you should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you have a extra **{** in this element:

```
.addmenu-item {
width: 190px;
height: 190px;
background: #F4F4F4;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-transition: color 50ms cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715);
-moz-transition: color 50ms cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715);
-o-transition: color 50ms cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715);
transition: color 50ms cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715);
}
} <--------
```

Delete this and must be work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using a plugin or something jQuery related but hopefully the below will help.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container{
         border: 1px solid #CCC;
         border-radius: 8px;
         height: 190px;
         width: 190px;
         float: left;
     }
    .container .image{
         height: 160px;
         width: 190px;
         overflow: hidden;
     }
    .container .caption{
         font-weight: bold;
         color: #666;
         background-color: #CCC;
         height: 14px; /* height 30px; */
         padding: 8px 6px;
     }
     .shadow{
         box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #AAA; /* adds a nice little shadow */
     }
</style>

<div class="container shadow">
    <div class="image"><img src="..."/></div>
    <div class="caption">Text goes here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that method of explicitly mentioning the image width and height. But I want to use overflow to make the image appear good. Please check the zerply link I've shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use pure CSS and make the background-image of the container the desired image, and set the background-size property to 'cover':

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted; it's not a full answer to the question with code, but it's a valid option in this situation, and it requires no javascript or jQuery

Comment: works fine for me. but I need to use the fadeIn/fadeOut and that apparently doesn't work for the background image :(